# sencha touch 2 stop audio when sliding to next card in carousel?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, carousel

With sencha touch 2, in a carousel, how can I stop the audio on the current card when I swipe forward or back to the next?

```
{
xtype: 'carousel',
iconCls: 'action',
style: 'background-color: #00A9A6;',
layout: { type:'hbox', pack:'start', align:'stretch' },
items: [
Ext.create('Ext.Container', { layout: 'hbox',
  items: [ 
  {
    items: [ { xtype: 'toolbar',
           docked: 'left', 
           layout: { type:'hbox', pack:'start', align:'stretch' },

            html: [
                "<audio id=\"player1\"><source src=\"audio/page 1.mp3\" type=\"audio/mpeg\"></audio><div style=\"position:relative;height:1500px;width:100px;margin:auto;\"><button class=\"pausebutton\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('player1').pause()\"></button><br/><button class=\"playbutton\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('player1').play()\"></button></div>"
            ].join("")
}], 
  }, 
  image_1
  ]
}),

Ext.create('Ext.Container', { layout: 'hbox',
  items: [ 
  {
    items: [ { xtype: 'toolbar',
               docked: 'left', 
               layout: { type:'hbox', pack:'start', align:'stretch' },

                html: [
                "<audio id=\"player2\"><source src=\"audio/page 2.mp3\" type=\"audio/mpeg\"></audio><div style=\"position:relative;height:1500px;width:100px;margin:auto;\"><button class=\"pausebutton\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('player2').pause()\"></button><br/><button class=\"playbutton\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('player2').play()\"></button></div>"
                ].join("")
    }], 
  }, 
  image_2
  ]
})
}
```

There are about 30 similar slides each with an image and a toolbar with custom play and pause buttons. What's strange is when I swipe to the next slide the audio from the previous is still playing, if I swipe again, to a third slide, the audio from the first then stops. I'd like it to stop on the second slide. I'll try the activeitemchange listener.

Listener added to carousel:

```
listeners:{
            activeitemchange:function()
            {
                var activeIndex = this.getActiveIndex();
                document.getElementById('player'+activeIndex).pause();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you swipe left/right to change to another item, your carousel will fire **activeitemchange** event. A good idea to go is to create a listener for that event and call commands to stop the audio.

Because you didn't provide any source code so that's my hint for now.

Comment: added some source for the carousel, i'll try adding some listeners.